# What is the best way to compare a openssl generated rsa public key in a file with multiple public keys in another file?

Tags: python-3.x, pki

I have a file `A.crt` with a single public key in it. I need to compare/check the existence of A.crt pub key in `B.crt` which is a consolidated file with multiple public keys.

`A.crt`

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

`B.crt`

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

**USECASE:**

We want to implement a key rotation script in python, which delete the obsolete public key from consolidated public keys file which is fed to a server.

**PLAN**

1. Load `A.crt` file into a varA.
2. Load `B.crt` file into a varB.
3. Trying to split the string using regex [ Im Not successful ]
   `(-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----.*-----END PUBLIC KEY-----)`
4. Compare existence of VarA in VarB and delete it.

Please suggest if the approach seems okay or any other better ways to handle this.

Comment: If the file is splited in lines you don't need to use regex. Just loop over each line with a key and check if varA matchs it.

Comment: @ArthurPereira `B.crt` is a multiline file where each key is also multiline. I tried with splitlines but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple parser like this to read all the public keys like this

```
import io

txt = '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''



start_str = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----'
stop_str = '-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'

pk = []
found = False
with io.StringIO(txt) as f:  # can be replaced by with open(file, 'r') as f
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == start_str:
            found = True
            continue
        if line == stop_str:
            found = False
            continue

        if found and line:
            pk.append(line)

print(pk)  # --> ['AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', 'BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB', 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC']
```

You can also use the `crypto` library to read RSA but I am not sure it supports multiple keys. see example [here](https://www.kite.com/python/examples/4914/crypto-load-an-rsa-key-from-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `openssl` has [propper methods](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/openssl-tutorial-ssl-certificates-private-keys-csrs) to look for a key in a file. But if you want to hardcode this and also delete the key in the original file that would be my approach for the step3 in your plan:

```py
def subscribe_key(old_file, new_file):
    with open(old_file, 'w') as key_file:
        for line in new_file:
            key_file.write(line)


def check_key(key, file):
    with open(file, 'r') as key_file:
        varB = key_file.readlines()  # read file

    for index, line in enumerate(varB):
        if line.strip() == '-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----':
            cur_idx = index
            cur_key = ''  # start to mount key

        elif line.strip() == '-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----':  
            if key == cur_key:  # compare keys
                del varB[cur_idx:(index + 1)]
                subscribe_key(file, varB)  # subscribe old file
                return True

        else:
            cur_key += line.strip()  # append strings to mount key

    return False


print(check_key(varA, "B.crt"))
```